# Dereference causes error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, dereference

When I use a dereference in a function as an argument, the preprocessor spits out an error.
I believe the * right before the parentheses causes ambiguity with the compiler.
Is there any way to get around this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char *in = NULL;
  char *out = NULL;
  getline(cin,in*);//error
  out=system(in*);//error
  printf(out);
  return 0;
}
```

The errors are on marked lines.
Thank you!

Comment: Does anyone besides me see the question "Why doesn't my program *still* fail to compile after changing to `*in`"?

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing `in` is written `*in`, not `in*`.  (Also, even with that fixed, your program still won't work, as you're trying to dereference `NULL`, and the second argument to `getline` will have the wrong type.  `char*` strings do not work the way you think they work.)

Comment: There is not even a matching overload for `std::getline(std::cin, *in)`, nor for `std::getline(std::cin, in)` !  (and rightly so)

Answer (score 0):

`getline` only works with C++ strings (not C-style strings). C++ strings can allocate memory as they go, in response to how much data is read.

There are other functions for reading into C strings, but you must pre-allocate the amount of memory you want, and also specify to the function how much memory you have allocated. In general there is no reason to do this, as the C++ string version is much simpler and less prone to error.

Also, avoid including C-style standard headers (i.e. ending in `.h`) and avoid using pointers. And `system` returns an int, not a string.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>    // cin, cout
#include <string>      // string
#include <cstdlib>     // system

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    int system_result = std::system( s.c_str() );
    std::cout << system_result << "\n";
}
```